# how re.compile works

Tags: python, regex, compilation

i got some confused in re.compile function bellow, i know it compile to detect all non printable chars.  but i'm not sure about the meaning of the parameter put in the compile function. thank you guys!

```py
re_print = re.compile('[^%s]' % re.escape(string.printable))
```

Comment: Are you asking what the pattern `[^abc]` means, or are you asking what `re.compile()` does?

Comment: actually i ask for the meaning of the parameter put in compile func, sorry for my bad english

Comment: that mean i want to know how re.compile work in this situation. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking this down to see if it helps. Run the following code in your python3 interpreter:

```
import string
import re

# This will be the contents of the variable referenced
print(string.printable)

# This is what happens after all those characters are escaped by re
print(re.escape(string.printable)

# This is the whole value you are giving to re.compile (the re_print):
 print('[^%s]' % re.escape(string.printable))
# Note the ^ in front means anything NOT printables
```

re_print is likely being used to check some text for non-printable characters (not in string.printable), but some of them need to be escaped or if not, re will not get the expected results because the special characters may be interpreted as a regex statement.

Comment: thanks! your explain make me clear. it just escape the special char use in regex by a back slash before each of them. and compile func will know exactly what to do (what result we expect to get :)). thank you very much!